# Understanding ByteBuffer

Tags: java, int

I'm trying to convert array of 4 bytes to int with `ByteBuffer`. Here is what I tried:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int i = ByteBuffer.allocate(4)
           .put(new byte[]{(byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 1})
           .getInt(); //BufferUnderflowException
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/oULWJj)

But this method throws `BufferUnderflowException`. Why? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Note that the `(byte)` casts aren't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to read from the `ByteBuffer`, you must flip it first!

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) of `Buffer#flip`:

> After a sequence of channel-read or put operations, invoke this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get operations.

Example:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

b.put(new byte[]{(byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 1});

b.flip();

System.out.println(b.getInt());

>> 1
```

Comment: Clarification: ByteBuffer does sequential reading/writing. Flip "switches between reading and writing." Resetting the position to 0. So actually the original codes was reading from position 4, yielding a buffer underflow.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively create the `ByteBuffer` so it *initially contains* the bytes, instead of `put`ting them:

```
    System.out.println (ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{0,0,0,1}).getInt());
```